# How do i retireve individual out put records for duplicate inputs in sql?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a set of inputs out of which some may  be duplicated. In the result too i need the output to be duplicated. i.e. each input should have an output even if the input is duplicated.

The query I'm trying to execute is:

```
select imsi 
from subscriber 
where business_id in ('4162000324','4162000324','4162000324','4162000321','4162000321') ;
```

My current output is :

```
imsi
302610914502037
302610913095231
```

But i want the output to be of 5 rows in which first 3 rows give the same imsi for the first `business_id(4162000324)` and last 2 rows give the same imsi for the 2nd `business_id (4162000321)`

Comment: If the table physically contains only one row against business_id '4162000324', then you can not get 3 resultant rows of any column belonging to that row while using the IN clause. 

I am not sure if its possible by manipulating your query somehow to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a `join`:

```
select s.imsi 
from subscriber s join
     (select '4162000324' as id from dual union all
      select '4162000324' from dual union all
      select '4162000324' from dual union all
      select '4162000321' from dual union all
      select '4162000321' from dual 
     ) ids
     on s.business_id = ids.id;
```

If you want these in the same order, then add an additional column for the ordering:

```
select s.imsi 
from subscriber s join
     (select '4162000324' as id, 1 as n from dual union all
      select '4162000324', 2 from dual union all
      select '4162000324', 3 from dual union all
      select '4162000321', 4 from dual union all
      select '4162000321', 5
     ) ids
     on s.business_id = ids.id
order by ids.n;
```

Comment: I tried the first query, but was getting an error like "FROM keyword missing". So i altered it to the below query and it executed.


select s.imsi from subscriber s join
     (select '4162000324' as id from subscriber union all
      select '4162000324' from subscriber union all
      select '4162000324' from subscriber union all
      select '4162000321' from subscriber union all
      select '4162000321' from subscriber 
     ) ids
     on s.business_id = ids.id;


But the result generated had more than 50K records instead of 5 records.

Comment: You can replace `union all` with `union` in your query.  What database are you really using?  This answer's syntax is valid for MySQL which is what your question is tagged.

Comment: My apologies. I'm using Oracle SQL developer.
I am getting the same error(ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected) even after replacing "union all" with "union".

Comment: Also please note that the table physically contains only one row against each business_id.
But my desired output is that for 'n' number of same inputs(business_id), i would need 'n' outputs(imsi).
Also i will be using this query in VBA wherein the input (business_id) is taken form a column say 'A' and the resultant imsi from the query will be populated in another column say 'B'. The inputs may have repeated values in different rows.

Comment: @Parthibansundararaj . . . I updated the answer for Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP

> array_unique

Try This

```
$business_array = array('4162000324','4162000324','4162000324','4162000321','4162000321');

$business = array_unique($business_array);

$business = implode("','",$business);

echo "select imsi 
from subscriber 
where business_id in ('".$business."') ;";
```

**OUTPUT**

```
select imsi from subscriber where business_id in ('4162000324','4162000321') ;
```